# How can I import files with less polys?

Tags: objects, import, .fbx

Every time I import an model of obj or fbx format into my scene blender the object has so many verts and edges where as I could trace the shape at a fraction of the polys, Is there anyway round this?

Answer (score 1):

Blender imports the current state of the object (OBJ, FBX,...). In order to import a low poly version, you need to have a low poly version already made. You can try to decimate or perform retopology to get that. For retopology you can do this directly in Blender, or if it is a OBJ file you can try InstantMeshes. For decimation, you can try Blender's modifiers, or MeshLab (look on hot to perform a point subsample of the current mesh, then you can go Delauney or Poisson or other methods to reconstruct the decimated mesh with the subsampled cloud). You can also try MeshMixer and do a simplify operation. After all that, you import the simplified version into Blender.